# Display two similar queries in one table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a query which will return which garment generated the most revenue during the last three months compared to the same period last year.
I want to display the results in one table. The garment_id from the queries might match but might not. If it matches then I would like to display the results in the same row. I suppose I want to order by garment_id.

I have so far come up with this which almost works but returns incorrect/strange values for TotalDaysHired, MoneyIn, LastYrTotalDaysHired and LastYrMoneyIn; I've no idea why. I've also tried joining the two queries with an inner join ON a.garmentid = b.garmentid order by a.garmentid which wouldn't even run.

```
SELECT garment_hire_line.date_out as 'dateout', 
        garment_hire_line.garment_id as 'garmentid', 
        catalogue.description as 'description', 
        SUM(garment_hire_line.days) AS 'TotalDaysHired', 
        SUM(garment_hire_line.days*catalogue.daily_rate) AS 'MoneyIn', 
        '' as 'LastYrTotalDaysHired', 
        '' as 'LastYrMoneyIn'
FROM garment_hire_line
    INNER JOIN garment ON garment_hire_line.garment_id = garment.garment_id
    INNER JOIN catalogue ON garment.catalogue_id = catalogue.catalogue_id
WHERE garment_hire_line.date_out>DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
GROUP by garment_hire_line.garment_id
UNION
SELECT garment_hire_line.date_out as 'dateout', 
        garment_hire_line.garment_id as 'garmentid', 
        catalogue.description as 'description','' as 'TotalDaysHired',
         '' as 'MoneyIn', 
        SUM(garment_hire_line.days) AS 'LastYrTotalDaysHired', 
        SUM(garment_hire_line.days*catalogue.daily_rate) AS 'LastYrMoneyIn'
FROM garment_hire_line
    INNER JOIN garment ON garment_hire_line.garment_id = garment.garment_id
    INNER JOIN catalogue ON garment.catalogue_id = catalogue.catalogue_id
WHERE garment_hire_line.date_out<DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
AND garment_hire_line.date_out>DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL '1:3' YEAR_MONTH)
GROUP by garment_hire_line.garment_id
```

**garment_hire_line**

```
garment_line_id date_out Days return_date discount hire_id garment_id
8               12/06/2012  4   16/06/2012  0          1        4
9               12/06/2012  5   17/06/2012  0          1        2
10              12/06/2012  4   16/06/2012  0          1        4
11              11/07/2012  3   14/07/2012  10         2        2
12              10/08/2012  3   13/08/2012  0          3        4
13              09/09/2012  2   11/09/2012  5          4        3
14              09/01/2017  3   12/09/2017  0          5        3
```

**Catalogue**

```
catalogue_id|   description|     designer|    Type|    daily_rate|  supplier_name|  supplier_purchase_price|    date_purchased| quantity|
    1             Hat        Elizabeth Kate Accessory        3       Lids              25                         28/02/2017    3
    2             Dress      Calvin Klein   Designer Outfit 20       Glam              260                        12/05/2012    2
    3             Handbag        Gucci      Accessory        4       Hold On           200                        01/01/2017    4
    4             Witches Dress  null       Fancy Dress      12      Fancy Fred        74                         21/05/2012    7
```

**Garment**

```
garment_id  Colour    sizing    catalogue_id    location_id supplier_id
1           Black     Medium           1           2           1
2           Black     10               2           2           2
3           Black     8                2           2           3
4           Black     0                3           2           4
5           Red       Child            4           2           1
6           Black     Medium           1           2           2
7           Black     10               2           2           3
```

Comment: What makes the values not what you expect? I suggest you include sample data of the tables involved, and the expected output you want for that data.

Comment: Apologies, yes that would help. I've added in a screenshot just below the code. the top link shows what the code displayed returns and the bottom link shows the correct values returned (but not as I would like it displayed) along with the tables which the data is being pulled from.

Comment: It would be more useful if you would provide all that as text, not as image. Even better would be a script so we can create the tables, load the data, and execute the SQL.

Comment: Sorry, I can't get the data to format properly when pasting in and don't have the means of providing a link to the files.

Comment: Indent each line with 4 spaces: you can do this by selecting the text (table formatted with pipe symbols) and pressing Ctrl+K: then every line gets indented with 4 spaces, so that it is displayed monospaced without linewrapping.

Comment: Also, you did not provide data for the `garment` table.

Comment: I'm afraid that's still not perfect but I really am a bit of a novice. The piece of code at I have posted took me hours and I can't find any other threads which help. It may be due to my lack of understanding.

Comment: OK, but you posted two tables, while your query has 3. What you posted under the heading "garment", probably is "catalogue", and you still need to include the table "garment".

Comment: All there now and labelled correctly. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that in your SQL query you use `''` for some fields that really are supposed to return numerical data. So you get some records with `''` and 3.00 in the same column, which is a conflict in data type. This causes some undesired conversions leading to the garbage output you saw.

Fix this by replacing `''` with `null`.

But you might also want to look into some other issues:

- As you group by the garment ID, you have no control over which date is being displayed in the first column when a particular garment was hired multiple times in the same period. 
  In fact this query would not be valid in newer versions of MySql (unless you set an option to allow it) and violates standard SQL rules. So you should either remove that column from the query, or apply an aggregation function to it (like `MAX`), or group by it.
- By using a `union` you will not really take advantage of showing the two periods side-by-side:  2 out of the 4 fields in one record will always be `null`. You can do this without `union` and filter what you sum up with an expression in the `sum` aggregate function.

So I would suggest this query:

```
SELECT      MAX(garment_hire_line.date_out) as `LastDateOut`, 
            garment_hire_line.garment_id as `garmentid`, 
            catalogue.description as `description`, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN garment_hire_line.date_out > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
                 THEN garment_hire_line.days
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS `TotalDaysHired`, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN garment_hire_line.date_out > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
                 THEN garment_hire_line.days*catalogue.daily_rate
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS `MoneyIn`, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN garment_hire_line.date_out <= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
                 THEN garment_hire_line.days
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS `LastYrTotalDaysHired`, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN garment_hire_line.date_out <= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
                 THEN garment_hire_line.days*catalogue.daily_rate
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS `LastYrMoneyIn` 
FROM        garment_hire_line
INNER JOIN  garment ON garment_hire_line.garment_id = garment.garment_id
INNER JOIN  catalogue ON garment.catalogue_id = catalogue.catalogue_id
WHERE       garment_hire_line.date_out > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
         OR (   garment_hire_line.date_out > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 15 MONTH)
            AND garment_hire_line.date_out < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
            )
GROUP BY    garment_hire_line.garment_id
ORDER BY    1
```

If you prefer to have a separate line for each date, then remove the `MAX` function, but add `garment_hire_line.date_out` in the `GROUP BY` list.

Comment: That does return what I'm after. I may remove the date altogether from the results because it's potentially not that relevant. The query is certainly not something I would have arrived at without quite a bit more practice but it gives me a lot to research and learn from. Thanks very much!